# run a function in dask with pretrained model

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pytorch, dask

I have a quick question. I tried to run a function with dask as below

```
from dask import delayed
from dask.distributed import Client
import torch

def algo_ml(data):
   cared_indx = []
   not_cared = []
   pretrained_model_path = 'C:\\user\\d\\ner.pkl'
   model = torch.load(model)
   for indx, row in data.iterrows():
      text = row['text']
      pred = model.predict(text)
      if pred > 0:
         cared_indx.append(indx)
      else:
         not_cared.append(indx)
    return (cared_indx, not_cared)
 client = Client(n_workers=2)
 ml = delayed(algo_ml)(data)
 res = ml.compute()
```

When I run the line `res=ml.compute`. I got the error as below:

```
daemonic processes are not allowed to have children
```

I am struggled to make sense of this error. Can anyone help? I would appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe try loading the model outside the delayed function and pass it as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can most likely resolve this error by configuring the `distributed.worker.daemon` configuration setting to `False`.

Resources:

- [Dask docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/configuration-reference.html#distributed.worker.daemon) regarding worker configuration
- [Closed issue](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/5058) with similar problem
- [Merged PR](https://github.com/dask/distributed/pull/2739) allowing users to set workers as non-daemons